# Nginx rewrites correctly for one but not the other

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

Basically, I am trying to use the `proxy_pass` directive to call a remote API.

So far, this is what I got:

```
server {
  location /a {
    proxy_pass https://a.com;
    rewrite ^/a(.*)$ $1 break; # no trailing slash, defined in application code
  }
  location /b {
    proxy_pass https://b.com;
    rewrite ^/b(.*)$ $1 break; # no trailing slash, defined in application code
  }
  location / {
    # Rest of configuration
  }
}
```

I am stuck with the fact that `location /a` works fine but `location /b` doesn't for some reason (`HTTP/404`).

---

I tried using a trailing slash for `location /b` this way

```
location /b/ {
  proxy_pass https://b.com/;
  rewrite ^/b/(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

but this doesn't work either.

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my particular issue.

The two API servers are not configured the same way and I had to tweek the nginx config a bit.

- Server `b.com` needed a `proxy_set_header Host $host` directive and no `rewrite` directive
- Server `a.com` needed the `rewrite` directive but not the `proxy_set_header Host $host`

This leaves me with the following (working for me) config:

```
server {
    location /a {
        proxy_pass  https://a.com;
        rewrite ^/a(.*)$ $1 break;
    }
    location /b {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass  https://b.com;
    }
}
```